# DropDownList cant get selected values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm stucked at creating dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC.
ViewModel:

```
public MultiSelectList users { get; set; }
```

I set the values in controller:

```
var allUsers = db.Users.Select(u => new {
                id = u.UserId,
                name = u.Name
            }).ToList();
            model.users = new MultiSelectList(allUsers, "id", "name");
```

so selectbox values are set.
In view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.users, Model.users, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The problem is that if I select the value and click submit i get this error:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

I think the problem is in the way how I create the dropdownlist in view, I'm not sure how to set it, thanks.

EDIT: If I dont choose any user from dropdown all goes well, but if I choose then the error appears.

Comment: To which object is the error referring?  When is the code trying to create an instance of that object?

Comment: Remove the dropdown and try submitting again. Does it still error out?

Comment: "Does it still error out"? no, it came when I added this code to create the dropdown. EDIT- everything's ok when I comment the line in view

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fLcFZyRT //pls see edit in my post

Comment: DropDownLists's can only be a single selection, so using MultiSelectList is not correct.  Unless you actually want multiple selections, in which case DropDownList is not correct and you should be using a multiple selectable element like ListBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to post to the `MultiSelectList` property. That's not going to work regardless, but the specific error is related to the fact that `MultiSelectList` has no parameterless constructor, and there's no way for the modelbinder to new up a class with parameters. Anything involved in the modelbinding process *must* have a parameterless constructor.

What you should be doing is have an additional property like:

```
public List<int> SelectedUserIds { get; set; }
```

And, then bind to that in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUserIds, Model.Users)
```

Also, as you'll notice, I changed `DropDownListFor` to `ListBoxFor`. If you're wanting to have a select multiple, you need `ListBoxFor`.

Comment: his problem was with DropDownList not ListBox

Comment: The OPs problem wasn't directly related to either, but `ListBoxFor` is necessary if you're wanting a multiple select, which the OP's use of `MultiSelectList` seemed to imply.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is failing when trying to bind, so to prevent it from binding:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourMethod([Binding(Exclude = "users")] SomeViewModel model)
```

The post back should go to an IEnumerable to capture the selected items.

Add to view model

```
public IEnumerable UserList { get; set; }
```

Change view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserList, Model.users, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get selected user id from a dropdownlist you must add a property to your model

```
public MultiSelectList users { get; set; }
public int SelectedUser { get;set;}
```

And in view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUser, Model.users, new { @class = "form-control" })
```